# How do you find the standard matrix for a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

How do you find the standard matrix for a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ where $T(e_1) = (3, 1, 3, 1)$ and $T(e_2) = (-5, 2, 0, 0)$?

[image: matrix]

I do not know how to approach this problem.  I see multiple examples on the internet of how to do $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, but nothing on how to do $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, since $x=ae_1+be_2$, and $T$ is linear we have
\begin{align*}
Tx&=T(ae_1+be_2)\\
&=aTe_1+bTe_2\\
&=a\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\3\\1\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}-5\\2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}3&-5\\1&2\\3&0\\1&0\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}